# Solution verification: Derivative of the infinite power tower $y(x) = x^{x^⋰}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, power-towers

I was doing the problem $(x^{x^{⋰}})'$ and I would like someone to verify my solution:
\begin{align*}
&\left(y=x^{x^{^{⋰}}}\right)'\\
\implies & \;\left(y=x^{y}\right)'\\
\implies & \;\left(y^{\frac{1}{y}}=x\right)'\\
\implies & \;\left(\frac{\ln\left(y\right)}{y}=\ln\left(x\right)\right)'\\
\implies & \;\frac{y'-y'\ln\left(y\right)}{y^{2}}=\frac{1}{x}\\
\implies & \; y'-y'\ln\left(y\right)=\frac{y^{2}}{x}\\
\implies & \; y'=\frac{y^{2}}{\left(1-\ln\left(y\right)\right)x}\\
\implies & \; \left(x^{x^{⋰}}\right)'=\frac{\left(x^{x^{⋰}}\right)^{2}}{\left(1-\ln\left(x^{x^{⋰}}\right)\right)x} 
\end{align*}

Comment: I can't really see any errors with this myself, though I do notice your solution is different from the solution [blackpenredpen derived on his channel here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_l1lz26C2M), which makes me wonder if there's a reason for the difference.

Comment: Blackpenredpen's solution is

$$\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{y^2}{x - xy \ln(x)} = \frac{y^2}{x(1 - y \ln(x))}$$

OP's solution is, instead,

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y^2}{x(1-\ln(y))}$$

Though when I think about it now,

$$y \ln(x) = \ln(x^y) = \ln(y)$$

since $y=x^y$ (somewhat loosely speaking). So everything is actually fine.

Comment: Just for notation, we don't know how to take the derivative of an equation.  In the first four lines, each side should have the prime.  That would make it clear that going from the second to the third is not justified because powers and derivatives do not commute, nor do logs when you go from line 3 to line 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be easier would be to use Lambert function since$$ x^{x^⋰}= y \implies x^y = y\implies 1 = yx^{-y} = ye^{-y\log x}\implies 
y = \frac{W(-\log x)}{(-\log x)}$$ Let $t=-\log(x)$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\times\frac{dt}{dx}$$
$$\frac d{dt} \Big[\frac{W(t)}t\Big]=-\frac{W(t)^2}{t^2 (W(t)+1)}$$
$$\frac{dt}{dx}=-\frac 1x$$